# FSQRT not returning the right value

Tags: assembly, nasm, sqrt

The code below returns the value "448070899" instead of the sqrt(4) which is 2

```
segment .data 

heeder: db "%d", 0 



 x dd 16
 y dd 4
 segment .bss 
 array resd 10

 sum resd 1

SECTION .text 
 global _main 

 extern _scanf 
 extern _printf 

 _main: 

 push ebp 
 mov ebp, esp 

fldz

    fld dword[y]
 fsqrt
 fst dword[sum]
 mov eax, [sum]


push eax
push heeder
call _printf 
add esp, 8
 pop ebp 
 ret
```

its not returning the right number.......the number its returning is 448070899. That is not correct, the correct should be 2..because the square root of 4 is two.

Comment: Since you're writing assembly you should have a good shot at finding out what is wrong - and learning a bundle in the process! I suggest you debug the code and see what happens inside the FPU: If it does what it's supposed to (replace the top of stack value with its square root) then you'll know that the FPU is functioning correctly. If the initial TOS value - the input value - turns out to be something other than what you expected then you'll have to check previous steps to find the cause. The last time I heard of an x86 FPU not performing correctly was in the first half of the nineties and t

Answer (score 3):

Since you are apparently expecting integer result (due to the `%d` format) you should use the `FISTP` instruction that stores an integer. Similarly, your input `y` is also an integer, so use `FILD` to load it.

Also note you should clean up the FPU stack. If you remove the currently unused `FLDZ` then the `FISTP` will do the job.

If you ever switch to floating point result, remember that C automatically promotes `printf` arguments to double, so make sure you do that too.